# isset(_POST) not working properly

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to link this two file but not working, 
first file to mae option drop down form
secon file to print image
can any body give advise ??
Thank you for ur help

**File option reg** :

```
$spi1s[1]="01_SAT_MAX_DUR";
$spi1s[2]="01_SAT_MAX_INT";
$spi1s[3]="01_SAT_RTN_PRD";
$spi1s[4]="01_SAT_FREQ";
$spires1 = mysql_query("SELECT SPI FROM kekeringan where SPI like '%01_SAT%'");
$spirow1=mysql_fetch_array($spires1);
$spiTitle1=$spirow1["SPI"];
foreach ($spi1s as $spiTitle1) {
    echo "<option id=\"option\" value=\"".$spiTitle1."\" ";
    if (isset($_POST['plot']) && $_POST['plot'] == $spiTitle1) { echo "selected=\"SELECTED\" "; }
            echo ">
            $spiTitle1
    </option>";
    }
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";echo "</select></td>\n";
echo "<input id='option' type=\"submit\" name=\"getringan\" value=\"Submit\" />\n";
echo "</form>\n";
```

**File to print** :

```
if(isset($_POST['getringan'])){
$spi1s[1]="01_SAT_MAX_DUR";
$spi1s[2]="01_SAT_MAX_INT";
$spi1s[3]="01_SAT_RTN_PRD";
$spi1s[4]="01_SAT_FREQ";
$spires1 = mysql_query("SELECT SPI FROM ringan where SPI like '%01_SAT%'");
$spirow1=mysql_fetch_array($spires1);
$spiTitle1=$spirow1["SPI"];

    $image = "<div id=\"plot_res\" style='border:    none;width:810px;height:610px;margin:auto;padding:auto;'>";

    if ($_POST['plot'] == "01_SAT_MAX") {
            $image .= "<center><img src=\"../data/4_0_0.png\" /></center>";
            $image .= "</div>";
            echo $image;
    } elseif ($_POST['plot'] == "SPI_01_SAT_MAX_INT"){
            $image .= "<center><img src=\"../data/4_1_0.png\" /></center>";
            $image .= "</div>";
            echo $image;
    } elseif ($_POST['plot'] == "SPI_01_SAT_RTN_PRD"){
            $image .= "<center><img src=\"../data/4_2_0.png\" /></center>";
            $image .= "</div>";
            echo $image;
    } elseif ($_POST['plot'] == "SPI_01_SAT_FREQ"){
            $image .= "<center><img src=\"../data/4_3_0.png\" /></center>";
            $image .= "</div>";
            echo $image;

    } else {echo "fail";}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Where are those POST from? isset() not working means a seriously bugged php installation, which is the least likely problem

Comment: Where is your form oppening tag? Did you set method post to the form?

Comment: i only got Fail which mean i can not plot ,,, like missing the link by using _POST

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (array_key_exists('getringan', $_POST)) {
    ...
}
```

or if it's could be also get

```
if (array_key_exists('getringan', $_REQUEST)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But the problem when user choose "01_SAT_MAX" should be ploting but this scipt is not plotting ,,, no conditional is accepted so printing "fail"

Comment: try to change this in your code:
echo "<select id='getringan' name=\"getrsubmit\" />";

foreach(...)

echo "<input id='option' type=\"submit\" name=\"getrsubmit\" value=\"Submit\" />\n";

Comment: thanks but it make error, i have this actually at the top of file just i didn't check copy paste of my script here, it is

Comment: echo "<form name='reg' method='post' >\n";

Comment: I mean the select needs the name getringan and the submit button needs a different name tag.

Comment: sorry i don't get you ,,, would you please explain more or explain in code ??